# Spherical Bessel expansion of Green function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Any reference/advice would be good.

I can use eigenfunction to solve the Green function for

$$\Delta u(x) + k^2 u(x) = \delta(x - y)$$

boundary condition given as $u = 0$ on $\partial B(1)$, unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The Green function is given as

$$G(x, x') = \sum_{n,l,m}  \frac{2}{j_{n+1}(\beta_{nl}^2)} \frac{Y_n^m(\theta,\phi) Y_n^{m\ast}(\theta', \phi') j_n(\beta_{nl}r)j_n(\beta_{nl}r')}{k^2 - \beta_{nl}^2}$$

What I wonder is if there is a similar expansion (spherical Bessel expansion with explicit series)for the Green function for free space.

$$G(x, x') = \frac{e^{ik|x - x'|}}{4\pi|x - x'|}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is an expansion.  Write for $r<r'$ and $r>r'$ separate expansions, valid for the respective regions.  Then enforce continuity at $r=r'$ and discontinuity of the first partials and you will have it.  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV is that working for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I think I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expansion (according to Varshalovich-5.17.4-19):
\begin{eqnarray} \label{pswf-exp}
\frac{e^{ik|x-x'|}}{|x-x'|} = 4\pi i k \sum_{\lambda, \mu} \left[j_{\lambda}(kx_<) h_{\lambda}^{(1)}(kx_>) \right]  \, 
Y_{\lambda \mu}^{*}({\hat{x}}) Y_{\lambda \mu}^{}({\hat{x'}}) 
\end{eqnarray}